# case statement if table present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having problem in finding table from different database (table sometimes get dropped due to procedure) if the table is present then condition else direct ans as 1

select (case when exists (select * from SysSet.INFORMATION_SCHEMA .TABLES  where TABLE_NAME = 'CHQPASS') then  (
                case when left(tranm.docu_no,1) <>'3' or tranm.docu_dt <'01/01/2015' then 1
                when (select top 1 ACHD_KEY from TRAND k where k.TRN_NO = TRANM.TRN_NO and k.DR_CR ='D' ) = 'A000100010002' THEN 1 
                WHEN  (select COUNT(*) from SYSSET..chqpass  D where D.COMP_DIR ='PSAGR' and D.DOCU_DT = TRANM.DOCU_DT and D.AMT = TRAND.TOT_AMT ) <> 0 
                THEN 1 
                else cast(isnull (trand.RECONCILE,0)as int)
                end)
                else 1
    end )as pend

if table is not present it show the error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid object name
>   'SYSSET..chqpass'.

table not present how can i stop it to see that table

Comment: Which DBMS  mysql or sql server ?

Comment: Do you have a DB named `SYSSET` also in that there should be table `chqpass` present in `dbo` schema

Comment: Removed mysql tag since error msg clearly says it is sql server

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding code comments.

Comment: its sql server i have sysset database (chqpass table get deleted due to procedure but i want that table is not present then ans should be one)

Comment: Which schema is here `SYSSET..chqpass` ??

Comment: @CoderofCode - If you keep double dot then `DBO` schema will be used

Comment: Maybe you should think about NOT allowing some table to delete "due to procedure"? It doesnät look like good DB design. If this is not possible, you have to use dynamic SQL to deal with vanishing tables.

Comment: @arvo buddy u r ryt its not good db design i am new be in this company and thing is that i am trying to work on that but till then what can i do is this only bcz i am on live project 

i have made another query to solve that prob it is working in if condition in coding but can i do it in sql with case statement or something else

Comment: I made it but not making table to delete thus close the topic 


thanks all :) :D for trying to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following line

```
WHEN  (select COUNT(*) from SYSSET..chqpass  D where D.COMP_DIR ='xyz' and D.DOCU_DT >'01/01/2015' and D.AMT = 2556 ) <> 0
```

with this line

```
WHEN  EXEC('(select COUNT(*) from SYSSET..chqpass  D where D.COMP_DIR =''xyz'' and D.DOCU_DT >''01/01/2015'' and D.AMT = 2556 )') <> 0
```

It should work this way...

Comment: it dint worked first i tried that only it first look in table as that is not present and shows that error

Comment: Okay, can you try putting the complete query in 'EXEC' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this try replacing the `sys.tables` with `INformationschema` so you can specify which `schema` the table is present in.

```
SELECT 
     (
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYSSET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CHQPASS' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
             THEN (
                   CASE WHEN LEFT(tranm.docu_no,1) <>'3' or tranm.docu_dt < '01/01/2015' THEN 1  
                        WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 ACHD_KEY FROM TRAND k WHERE k.TRN_NO = TRANM.TRN_NO and k.DR_CR ='D' ) = 'A000100010002' THEN 1 
                        WHEN  (select COUNT(*) from SYSSET..chqpass  D WHERE D.COMP_DIR ='PSAGR' and D.DOCU_DT = TRANM.DOCU_DT and D.AMT = TRAND.TOT_AMT ) <> 0  THEN 1 
                        ELSE cast(isnull (trand.RECONCILE,0)as int)
                   END
                  )
      ELSE 1  
      END 
     ) as pend
```

Comment: Sorry to say but it dint :( 


is it compulsory to have that table (if the table is present it works fine) and not there then it throws error that table is not present

Comment: Which sql server your using ?? And did you running only this part of query ?? OR there is more to the query ??

Comment: it is a big query , I am using sqlserver 2008  (u can say biggest query of my life )

Comment: I have tested above query with my table names it is working correct here might be issue with other part of query can you post your complete query in question.

Comment: I have posted it down please have a look might be something would be wrong in other parts

Comment: You didn't applied the `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'` in your exist query try using that.

Comment: It did work in my other query but not this one might be something is more wrong in my query 


thanks :) \